# WPF style info from external text file

Tags: wpf, vb.net, styles

Not sure if this is possible, but I have a WPF application that now has a requirement to be skinnable.

Basically, this equates to several key colours and a couple of logos.

Is there any way of grabbing the hex values for the colours in defined styles from an external (ie comes with the application but isn't compiled) text/xml file?

I want to be able to select the colours, create the file and then deploy to the user with the application so that I don't have to maintain multiple versions.

I'm not even sure that this is the best way to achieve what i'm after.
Has anyone done anything akin to this?

I would be extremely grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just hold the color values in a config file simple text file will suffice.
though you can use VisualStudio Resource file..

file will contain lines in each:

item_enum_name item_type item_value

for example:

main_screen_bg_color Color Black
company_logo URI \logos\logo1.jpg

and so on..

just load the file parse it and use bind to the values...

Comment: Thank you.
At least now I know I was at least heading in the right direction.
To be honest I was tying myself in knots.